Adjust margins and spacing of enumerate environment with the enumitem package
I have an ordered list of items that I want to behave exactly like sections.
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.65in]{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=1em, indent=0pt]{parskip}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{ipsum}

\begin{document}

\section*{1. Item A}

\ipsum[0]

\section*{2. Item B}

\ipsum[0]

\rule[0.25em]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Item A\\
\ipsum[0]
\item Item B\\
\ipsum[0]
\end{enumerate}

\rule[0.25em]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0pt]
\item Item A\\
\ipsum[0]
\item Item B\\
\ipsum[0]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


The sections behave exactly like what I am after, except that I need to manage the section type (i.e., section, subsection) and numbering.
The first enumerate is indented, the labels are offset and the text is further offset.
The second enumerate is closer, but the labels are too far left and hang outside the linewidth.
I don't see any way in the manual to accomplish this and all my attempts have failed.
How can I make an enumerate environment align exactly like sections?

See this answer for a detailed explanation of the options for horizontal spacing.

Setting only leftmargin is not enough:
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0pt,labelindent=0pt,labelwidth=1em,labelsep=5pt,itemindent=*]
\item Item A\\
\ipsum[0]
\item Item B\\
\ipsum[0]
\end{enumerate}


